# ngx-bootstrap Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ngx-bootstrap/loader'

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using datepicker from ngx-bootstrap@3.2.0 in an Angular 6.1.10 project. 
I'm also loading a different locale (nlLocale).

In my feature module:

```
import { defineLocale, nlLocale, BsDatepickerModule, BsLocaleService} from 'ngx-bootstrap';

defineLocale('nl', nlLocale);
```

In my component:

```
import { BsLocaleService } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {  
  locale = 'nl';

  constructor(private bsLocaleService: BsLocaleService) {
    this.bsLocaleService.use(this.locale);
  }
}
```

When I build this using the command:

```
ng build --watch
```

I have no problems, I can run the app, use the datepicker and the months appear in Dutch.

However when I build for production:

```
ng build --prod
```

I get the following error:
**ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/fesm5/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ngx-bootstrap/loader' in 'E:\MyProject\node_modules\ngx-bootstrap\datepicker\fesm5'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/modal/fesm5/ngx-bootstrap-modal.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ngx-bootstrap/loader' in 'E:\MyProject\node_modules\ngx-bootstrap\modal\fesm5'**

I've looked for the file 'ngx-bootstrap-datepicker.js' which exists in 'fesm5' but I see no reference inside the file to anything related to ngx-bootstrap/loader'.

I've tried downgrading to ngx-bootstrap@3.0.1 and it does work so it obviously indicates a problem with ngx-bootstrap, but from some reading I've been doing others don't seem to be having this problem.

Anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 0):

Have you done following in the feature modal?

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),...]
})
```

if so, try o to add it to your root module instead

Comment: Tried both, same result

Comment: Can you update your post on how your modules look like?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using Angular 9 with the latest version of ngx-bootstrap.
I believe the latest implementation is to import the BsDatepickerModule in the app.module.ts file like this

**Import statement in app.module.ts code:**

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
```

**in app.module.ts imports:**

```
  imports: [
BrowserAnimationsModule,
BsDatepickerModule.forRoot()
```

]

**Component Code:**

```
import { BsDatepickerConfig } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';

@Component({ selector: 'app-', templateUrl: './register.component.html', styleUrls: ['./register.component.css'],
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {


bsConfig: Partial<BsDatepickerConfig>;



constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {

this.bsConfig = Object.assign({}, { containerClass: 'theme-blue' });

}
}
```

**package.json**

"@angular/core": "~9.1.7",
"bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.1",
"@angular/cli": "~9.1.6"
[image]

**From the official site:**

**Usage**

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

// RECOMMENDED

import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';

// NOT RECOMMENDED (Angular 9 doesn't support this kind of import)

import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({

imports: [

```
BrowserAnimationsModule,

BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),

...
```

]
})

export class AppModule(){}

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker

[techjunkieblog.com](https://www.techjunkieblog.com)

Comment: For the newer versions the import statment is import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';  You might have to rebuild after adding the library, and also use the Angular cli to add the tool instead of npm with this command ng add ngx-bootstrap type Ctrl+C to stop the app and ng serve --watch to rebuild it

Comment: I think from Angular 6-8 you can still follow the old implementations.  The best strategy is to identify the ngx-bootstrap version in your package.json file and find the documentation in the official site https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/ that matches your version